# When, where and how does Visual Studio 2017 set the DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE environment variable

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017

When creating a new .NET core application with docker support in Visual Studio 2017 it creates a number of docker-compose.yml files. The docker-compose.vs.debug.yml and the release variant both contain contain a reference to an environment variable named DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: app:dev
    build:
      args:
        source: ${DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE}
    environment:
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ~/.nuget/packages:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
      - ~/clrdbg:/clrdbg:ro
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    labels:
      - "com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetoperatingsystem=linux"

The purpose of this variable seems to be a reference to the source directory, however, it always seems to be empty.
```

I was unable to find more detailed info on this subject... Does anyone have an idea or a pointer to some docs?

Comment: My docker build was working just fine until a VS2017 update stopped setting that value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with doing some setup that can be used with Visual Studio Team Services CI/CD. However when run locally, that value is empty and if you look at the docker file, you see that if the value is empty, it substitutes "obj/Docker/publish"

Dockerfile:

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0

ARG source

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

**COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .**

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]

However for me, i don't actually see that folder or anything in it. Where the "magic" happens is in the volumes section. that essentially moves your code onto the container as a [bind mound](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume). this is where your code gets moved onto the container. There are a few other things that happen that aren't clear to me though because I see a line in the build output where the code gets built/published, but not the actual command that is running.

Answer (score 0):

This has no real impact when building development images. As Nick explained we get code using bind mount.

This is used when building images for production use with file `docker-compose.ci.build.yml`, which outputs to obj/Docker/publish of each solution web project.